# Mocking class variable with mocker in pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a problem roughly looking like this:

In a file `data.py` I have

```py
from typing import ClassVar
from tinydb import TinyDB
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Data:
    db: ClassVar = TinyDB("some_path")

    @property
    def some_data(self):
        return 100
```

I would like to mock the `some_data` method.

I tried:

```py
import pytest
import pandas as pd
from package1.data import Data

@pytest.fixture
def mocked_raw_data(mocker):
    m = mocker.patch.object(
        Data, "some_data", return_value=10, new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock
    )

    )
    return m

def test_some_data(mocked_raw_data):
    assert Data().some_data == 2
```

But obviously this gives an error with the `db` method class variable. How can I mock this variable as well? Does my approach generally make sense?

Answer (score -1):

Did you use `@pytest.mark.django_db`?

This would help in testing data on a separate DB rather than the production one.

And regarding your question on mocking, you can use monkey patch for mocking

For eg,

```
def test_user_details(monkeypatch):
        mommy.make('Hallpass', user=user)
        return_data = 
            {
            'user_created':'done'
            }
        monkeypatch.setattr(
            'user.create_user', lambda *args, **kwargs: return_data)
        user_1 = create_user(user="+123456789")
        assert user_1.return_data == return_data
```